# Entity framework many to many but also a relationship can occur more than once

Tags: entity-framework, orm

I do not know how to define this relationships. I have users and badges, users can collect many badges, they can also have a certain badge more than once. (Just like Stackoverflow).

How can I define this numberOfTimesEarntBadge count?

I've tried simply going user.badges.add(badge) again, but it doesn't get inserted into database.

At the moment, badges is defined (inside user class) as:

```
public virtual ICollection<Badge> Badges { get; set; }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a relationship entity e.g. UserBadge, so the nav property would be ICollection UserBadges

UserBadge would have a nav property to User and to Badge, as well as a PK ID field.

To then get a count of badges, you would group a user's UserBadges ICollection by Badge, then count each group:

```
var badgeCountQuery =
for ub in userEntity.UserBadges
group ub by ub.Badge into g
select new
{
    Badge = g.Key,
    BadgeCount = g.Count()
};
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I have thought of this solution, I'd like to avoid creating a new class, so this looks good, but let's see if anyone else has a more elegant solution..